# Giving iframe properties from inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, backbone.js

So I am currently working on an application that runs on top of the customers page inside its own iframe.

Application works in backbone and everything else except the initialization of the iframe is done inside the iframe. Initialization happens with a small javascript snippet that the client will copy to their footer.

The problem I'm currently having is that I have to inject a CSS file to the parent site in order to style my iframe correctly when it's rendered and I really don't think that I should tamper with clients page at all since CSS might have some conflicts in it.

Is there any better way to style the iframe than the current way of doing it?

Comment: `better than current way`.... what is your current way? How is iframe inserted in page (script, user copy paste etc)? More details would help

Comment: iframe gets initiated through a init script in the clients website and before its rendered I have to inject a CSS file to the client site in order to style the iframe. This is the only part that I have to do outside the iframe, everything else after this runs only there to avoid any tampering with the customer site.

Comment: can put the css inline using your insertion script although  with proper namespacing should be easy to avoid stylesheet collision since you are only styling your widget/iframe. Make sure it has very unique ID/classes

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two different options;

**Inline iframe styles**
Give your client a pre-styled iframe to embed, like this

```
<iframe src="yoururl.com/client" 
        frameborder="0" 
        style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 600px;">
</iframe>
```

**Embed through script tag**
Create a small script tag (that you host) that you give to your client. Inside the script you dynamically create the iframe dom element and possibly other external css-files that you need

Host a JS file, like *//yoururl.com/iframe.js*

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src","http://yoururl.com/client");
document.write("<div id='mycontainer'></div>");
document.getElementById("mycontainer").appendChild(iframe);
```

Then you can give this to your client to put in their page where they want the iframe to show up.

```
<script src="//yoururl.com/iframe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but it could be possible that no one is applicable:

1. Ask the client to style your iframe (inline or with css)
2. publish the iframed content on the same domain of the main website and check if the parent frame is accessible via javascript
3. Ask the Client to enable the header "X-Frame-Options". Maybe with something like "**ALLOW-FROM SAMEDOMAIN, www.youriframedomain.com**". It seems it is deprecated, check for **Content-Security-Policy** instead.
4. embed it via script tag
5. Check for [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage): it requires anyway an additional script in the main website that listens for the message (it could be the css text itself) from the iframe and applies the new style

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your css separately to the client. If that is not an option, then you need to do it the way you are doing now (injecting the parent style from within the iframe). However, this does not seem to be a good idea, unless your css rules are pretty unique.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `window.frameElement` to refer to the iframe element which your page is embedded in. With that reference, you should be able to modify the style attribute to change how the frame renders.

Comment: not cross domain you can't without setting `document.domain` inside iframe to match parent

Comment: It wasn't specified that it needed to work cross domain